# Evaluating a classifier in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, statistics, evaluation, auc

I was walking through [this tutorial](https://pythonprogramming.net/convolutional-neural-network-kats-vs-dogs-machine-learning-tutorial/).

I couldn't figure out how to evaluate the classifier, especially finding its sensitivity, specificity, AUC, ...etc.

I found those in the TensorFlow documentation ([this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/specificity_at_sensitivity), and [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/auc)), but couldn't figure how to use it with the code shown in the article.

How can I find such measures for the code shown in the article?

Comment: Just get the predictions from the classifier and use `sklearn` metrics functionality for the ease

Answer (score 0):

So as I see it, the tutorial is about classifying pictures, it's a dog or a cat. After completion of the training, you will be evaluated with a test data set (pictures that were not used in the training) for these test data points will make a prediction for the two classes (for example: cat: 0.08 dogs: 0.92) and then choose the class that has the highest value. Then compare whether the predicted class matches the label. Now you do this for example for 100 test images and then you have x wrongly detected and y correctly recognized test data sets. This will then calculate the accuracy of your model.

In Tensorflow you can find out if a picture has been correctly classified with something like this:

```
corr_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(logits, 1), label)
```

To evaluate several images at once: [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/in_top_k)